Booting to Busy Box shell (initramfs) after installing minecraft mods
Recently I decided I wanted to try out some shaders on minecraft. So, I installed iris and sodium for fabric (which was already installed), and the shaders sorta worked. It would work for a bit, then gradually turn the minecraft window white. Then, after playing for maybe 4 or 5 minutes, my monitor would stop receiving signal. I then had to press the reset button on my computer, which then made my computer boot into a busy box shell. I then had to press reset again, when the computer then complains about how "/dev/nvme1n1p2: has a file system with errors, check forced". Then proceeds to take forever checking nvme1n1p2. After it finishes, it says "/dev/nvme1n1p2: Orphan file (inode 12) block 26 is not clean". Then it says CLEARED and something about how some files are 0.0% non-contiguous and some large number of blocks. It has since then got worse. This morning, I waited maybe 15 to 20 minutes for it to turn on. It finally turned on, I logged in and left it for maybe a minute to blow my nose. Came back, monitor had no signal and had to go through the whole thing again. This happens at least once a day. Also, when I'm in the busy box shell sometimes I try to run the exit command, but it just says:
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory

And then I have to press the reset button on my computer to reboot. There is a sys folder, a proc folder, and a root folder so I have no idea what it's complaining about
UPDATE: I checked the file system using disks, and that said nothing was wrong with it. Also, I discovered if I create the directories /root/sys and /root/proc, exit doesn't fail. Now when I run exit, it just sits there. Doesn't print anything, just nothing. Is it possible somethings up with my RAM, sense it's booting to initRAMfs? Also, I did notice that it seems to happen whenever I bump either my computer, or my desk, or maybe I set my chair down to hard, or someone walks in too hard.
